# After applying code obfuscation exe take 1-3 minutes to run

Tags: c#, .net, obfuscation, desktop-application

I have applied code obfuscation through ConfuserEx tool on .NET C# project exe open immediately before applying obfuscation but after applying obfuscation it take 1-3 minutes to open and code obfuscation also reduce size of exe from 59MB to 41MB. Please suggest me new obfuscation tool or tell me proper use of ConfuserEx.

Comment: Are there any other visible problems except for the slow speed? Or does your application work as expected otherwise?

Comment: Please note software recommendations are off topic here. There is a sister site for that purpose though.

Comment: there are no other visible problems everything works fine as expected

Comment: I would recommend to open an issue at the ConfuserEx github page to get support. https://github.com/yck1509/ConfuserEx/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only try to answer the second part:

File size reduction is somewhat expected, because obfuscation removes all debug information and renames all method and variable names to very short ones (i.e. A, B, C). In your case, it's pretty significant, though.